# how to get browser type in Header UserAgent property with c#?

Tags: c#, http, server, http-headers, user-agent

I need to detect the browser type on c# my server side code

I have an `HttpContext context;` object on my server code

How do I access the `HeaderUserAgent` string value ?

`context.Request.Headers.` doesn't give me the intelisense for it

Comment: Does this help : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Did you try this ?  UserAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting UserAgent from header in string Use this code.

```
 string UserAgent = context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
```